# Remove settings icon on top-right in Windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

I m working on windows 8.1 metro app and this app Contains `settings` and `share` icon with label on top-right inside app menu. can anyone help-out to hide this `settings` and `share` icons from app.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a [SettingsFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn252814.aspx) somewhere?

Comment: @ChrisW. thanks for your response. but i have no settings flyouts. this share and settings menu appear on application runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that button shows up is because you've registered a settings charm.

Somewhere in your app's starting code (e.g. in app.xaml.cs, or in your mainwindow) is something like this:

```
SettingsPane settingsPane = SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView();
```

You can just remove this code if you don't want the charm.

A more concrete example on how to implement the settings charm can be found here: http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2013/11/13/working-with-the-settings-charm-for-windows-8-1-store-applications/)

Comment: @ Tom Wyuts there is nothing like `SettingsPane` in entire project or solution.